# Filtering PDO SQL Queries

Tags: php, mysql, select, filter, pdo

I'm using PDO method in my PHP page to implode two strings (in order to create a graph... long story!), but I don't know how to filter them. The table structure in MySQL is like this:

Column Name:
**item** (the name of the item being voted on);
**nvote** (the number of votes this item has received);
**date** (the dates of the votes)

This is what I have so far:

```
$stmt1 = $db->prepare("SELECT date FROM vote"); 
$stmt1->execute();

$stmt2 = $db->prepare("SELECT nvote FROM vote"); 
$stmt2->execute();

$line1 = implode( ',', $stmt1->fetchAll (PDO::FETCH_COLUMN) ); 
$line2 = implode( ',', $stmt2->fetchAll (PDO::FETCH_COLUMN) );
```

(Line1 creates the x-axis of my graph, line2 creates the y-axis)

This works very well to generate the strings for my graph.

How can I filter these so that name of the item being voted on (in the "**item**" column") is filtered by a var (in this case, `$nameofitem`)? I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to fetch both columns i one sql-query and filtering by using a WHERE-statement in the sql-query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$params = array(':value' => 'Hello World');
$stmt1 = $db->prepare("SELECT date FROM vote WHERE item = :value ORDER BY date"); 
$stmt1->execute($params);

$stmt2 = $db->prepare("SELECT nvote FROM vote WHERE item = :value ORDER BY date"); 
$stmt2->execute($params);

$line1 = implode( ',', $stmt1->fetchAll (PDO::FETCH_COLUMN) ); 
$line2 = implode( ',', $stmt2->fetchAll (PDO::FETCH_COLUMN) );
```

The key is adding a WHERE condition in the SQL query with a parameter that is bound by execute when passed an array.

Note that I also added an order statement for you as there is no guarantee of the result ordering without it, meaning the points you saw on the graph could have been associated with the wrong point. Date might not be the best choice, use a unique key if you can. Alternatively, you could fetch everything in a single query and build your lists with post-processing.

Comment: Dude... that is some epic programming! Thank you very much indeed.